# How to properly attempt to express a function in terms of new variables

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I have a specific problem in mind, but I am more interested in how to "properly" convey to Mathematica the result that I want. To start with, I have a function $G$ that can be represented like

$G=f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)$

and I want to find an expression $G(x,y)$ such that

$x=x_1+x_2\,,\quad y=y_1+y_2$

I know the form of $f$ and I want find $G(x,y)$. I know that $x$ and $y$ (also $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$) are linearly independent variables.

How can I properly instruct Mathematica to make manipulations to $G$ for this purpose? It is possible this cannot be done analytically, and if that is true I would like Mathematica to respond in a way that I can be certain that it cannot be done, or at least that Mathematica cannot accomplish this.

So far I have tried methods involving built in functions like FullSimplify, TrigReduce, TrigExpand, etc., but these functions don't have the same end goal in mind. I have also browsed the stack exchange, but I don't think I have found a satisfactory answer. Essentially what I want is a "proper" way of telling Mathematica the end goal I want so that the result I get is either the function $G(x,y)$ or something that indicates failure to find it.

Example:

```
f[x1_,y1_] := Sinh[2 x1]/(Cosh[2 x1] + Cosh[2 y1])
G = f[x1,y1]+f[x2,y2]
```

and I am looking for an expression

```
G[x,y] = G[x1+x2,y1+y2]
```

Comment: It would be good to have a concrete example in the post, in copy/paste format.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just a counterexample.  In addition to your definition of `f[x1,y1]`, let's define `h[x1,x2,y1,y2]`

```
ClearAll[f, h]
f[x1_, y1_] := Sinh[2 x1]/(Cosh[2 x1] + Cosh[2 y1])
h[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := f[x1, y1] + f[x2, y2]
```

How should one view `g[2x,y]`?  Should it be the same as `h[x,x,y,0]`?

```
h[x, x, y, 0]
```

$$\frac{\sinh (2 x)}{\cosh (2
   x)+\cosh (2 y)}+\frac{\sinh
   (2 x)}{\cosh (2 x)+1}$$

Or, is it `h[2x,0,y,0]`?

```
h[2 x, 0, y, 0]
```

$$\frac{\sinh (4 x)}{\cosh (4
   x)+\cosh (2 y)}$$

It seems the $G(x,y)$ you are asking for is not well defined for this particular (nonlinear) choice of `f[x1,y1]`.

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't make any sense to me. Should the Identification for `G[2x,y]` not be just `h[2x1,2x2,y1,y2]`? Why using `2x` would enforce either `y2=0` or `x2=y2=0` is not clear.

Comment: That's exactly the point I was trying to make -- the first argument of `G` does not enforce anything on $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Maybe you can *add a few examples to your question*.  Can you tell us what the function `G[6,2]` must evaluate to?  It seems like we could use $x_1=3+\lambda$ and $x_2=3-\lambda$, since those values are consistent with $x=x_1+x_2=6$ for any $\lambda$.  Can you tell us what to use for $\lambda$ in every case?

Comment: This is a lot more clear to me now, apologies. `x` and `y` are linearly independent variables, i.e. that every point in 2D space maps to a unique set `(x,y)` and changing `x` does not change `y`. This means that `(x1,x2,y1,y2)` cannot just be freely choosen. I do have definitions for the variables in terms of 2D Euclidean coordinates, but I didn't think it was relevant to the core question. For your two examples, any case where `x1=0` or `x2=0` is undefined and constraining `x1=x2` actually requires `y=0`. Do you think that in order to solve this problem, I require some sort of `λ` constraint?